# Text classification algorithms which are not Naive?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, data-science

Naive Bayes Algorithm assumes independence among features. What are some text classification algorithms which are not **Naive** i.e. do not assume independence among it's features.

Comment: This is off topic for a few reasons - too broad, primarily opinion based, it's a better fit for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), and "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Tchotchke - I fully agree that it is better suited for CV, however the question is not opinion based (it has a very clear statement which can be strictly answered) nor too broad (see answer provided).

Comment: @lejlot I see where you're coming from, but I consider it too broad and opinion-based because I don't think it can be strictly answered. There are dozens of algorithms that one could list out - at what point is the question answered? I was thinking it was opinion-based because I implicitly assumed that the OP would require some good options - not just a list of any possible ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be very straight forward, since nearly **every** classifier (besides **Naive** Bayes) is not naive. Features independence is very rare assumption, and is not taken by (among huge list of others):

- logistic regression (in NLP community known as maximum entropy model)
- linear discriminant analysis (fischer linear discriminant)
- kNN
- support vector machines
- decision trees / random forests
- neural nets
- ...

You are asking about text classification, but there is nothing really special about text, and you can use any existing classifier for such data.